# UniQuery LIST without page breaks

Tags: unidata, u2, uniquery

This should be simple but it's just not working. I have a list of records that I want to display in the terminal without anything besides the list of record keys. No Headers, page gaps, etc. The problem is I can't get rid of the page gaps that keep chopping up my list.

`SORT INVENTORY HDR.SUPP COL.HDR.SUPP NO.PAGE NO.SPLIT COUNT.SUP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your TERM settings, ignore the 'type' option.
Increase the TERM 'B' (HELP TERM) to the total number of records you are returning.

For example if the report contains **100** records, you enter:

: TERM  [to get default settings]

: TERM 80,**100**,132,60

: run LIST/SORT

: TERM A,B,C,D  [ use values from first TERM ]

You need to run the term command prior to running your select.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping the solution would be but at least now I don't have to bother with so much clean up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're trying to get this list of bare keys so you can copy/paste it somewhere else (like Excel), I'll throw out another option that may be helpful and save some scrolling:

```
:sort INVENTORY TO DELIM 9 /tmp/inventory.txt
```

Will run your command and dump the output (tab-delimited, though that's irrelevant with only one field) to a file in the tmp directory.

```
:UDT.OPTIONS 91 ON
```

Is helpful if you're dumping dates, numbers or anything that needs output formatting.

[UDT Options Command reference](https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20/unidata/previous%20versions/v7.2/unidata_udtoptionscommandsrefguide_v72.pdf) describes that:

> UDT.OPTIONS 91 U_LIST_TO_CONV
>   affects saved queries on
>   data that is defined in the dictionary with a conversion code. For
>   example, when a date is defined as D4, the internal date is 9611,
>   which the conversion code translates as 04/24/94. UniData does not
>   convert the data before it saves UniQuery results to an ASCII file.
>   With UDT.OPTIONS 91, you can force the conversion before UniData saves
>   the ASCII file.